# String size relation between java and C++

Tags: java, c++, string

I am working on a certain application built on Java. The java layer talks to C++ layer which does the logic of forming sql queries from database and returns the result back to the Java layer.

With a simpler example :

On the java side

```
nameField = new JTextField(20) //20 chars max length
name = t.getText() // name is sent to CPP layer
```

On the CPP layer, name from java layer is received and stored in a local variable say cppName. I am confused about the declaration of variables used in CPP layer. Most of them are declared like this :

```
char cppName[20*4+1]
```

I want to know the significance of 20*4+1 here. The reason for declaring all variables on cpp side with size as javaSize*4+1.

Comment: If the String is translated via UTF-8 each character can turn into 4-bytes. As CPP provides no protection if you overrun the string, you have to take the worst case size, even if you don't believe you will every use these characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the characters in the java code UNICODE? If so, a single `char` isn't enough to store a UNICODE character, the ratio is `4:1`. The final character (+1) is the null terminator.

So you need 4 bytes, which is 4 `char`s, in the C++ side to store a single Java character, and char-represented strings in C++ are null-terminated (last character has to be `'\0'`), so `20*4+1`.

Comment: I also remembered 4:1 ratio, but when I walked to give [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), it says: `char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).`. What am I missing? :\

Comment: @amit well yeah, but a wchar_t for example is on 4 bytes. It doesn't really make sense have a 2-byte storage.

Comment: @amit you looked ti up in the Java help. In C char is 8bit and your conversion seems to generate Utf8 string.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore This is what I thought, but why does the official tutorial say 16 bits then? Is it a mistake? Or I (and you) just remembered it incorrectly? :|

Comment: @amit why would storing 16 bits in 32 bits be a mistake? It's probably  like that in the C++ side for direct conversion to a wide character.

Comment: CPP: char is 8bit. wchar_t is depending on the platform either 16 or 32 bit. In Java 16bit is used which means Utf16

Comment: I guess there is some misunderstanding about unicode here. Unicode comes in different flavors (e.g. UTF8, UTF16, UTF32) in big and little endian. The numbers represent the minimum bit width of a character. Some characters are longer symbol sequences ("escaping"). Java uses UTF16 and the longer symbol sequences are few so most of the time they are ignored. This explains the char type.

Comment: Thanks both for the explanation, I guess I just read the answer out of context.

Answer (score 2):

If the String is translated via UTF-8 each character can turn into 4-bytes. As CPP provides no protection if you overrun the memory reserved, you have to take the worst case size, even if you don't believe you will every use these characters.

BTW In Java String are stored as UTF-16 which means it supports characters above 65535 as code points using two chars.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/Supplementary/

The longest character for supported code points in Java turns into 4 bytes when UTF-8 encoded.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.appendCodePoint(Character.MAX_CODE_POINT);
System.out.println(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8").length); // prints 4
```

though this technically takes up two `char` in the String. If you take the largest character you get 3. So really 4 is overly conservative (as it takes two chars to make 4 bytes)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.appendCodePoint(Character.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8").length); // prints 3
```

Comment: Utf8 has a 6 byte max size, not 4.

Comment: Can you give an example in Java?

Comment: That happens when I answer things from the smartphone in the middle of the night (i.e. before 8am). Turns out you're completely right, but: `Many pieces of software added UTF-8 conversions for UCS-2 data and did not alter their UTF-8 conversion when UCS-2 was replaced with the surrogate-pair supporting UTF-16. The result is that each half of a UTF-16 surrogate pair is encoded as its own 3-byte UTF-8 encoding, resulting in 6-byte sequences rather than 4 for characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane. Oracle databases use this, as well as Java and Tcl as described below`

Comment: Source is [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8#CESU-8) - so you're pretty much right. It later says something about Java using the 6 byte scheme for object serialization and JNI, but not external encryption so that's not to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Java characters are unicode, so if you like to pass them to  C  as ascii you will have to 
use string.getBytes(charset()) - will give you  byte array of desired charset.     On C side you will have to add terminating null byte - hence +1